# JMeter SSL Protocol switching between requests

Tags: ssl, redirect, jmeter, protocols

Our main site is behind a Single sign on server (SSO - Oracle identity Manager).

The main site uses TLSv1.2 as the protocol whereas the SSO uses TLSv1 protocol.

Main site -> TLSv1.2

SSO site -> TLSv1

When SSO (singlesignon) is successful, it redirects to the main site.

My problem: 
How do I switch protocols from TLSv1 to TLSv1.2 between SSO and the redirected site within Jmeter ?

So far I have tried :
system.properties`

https.socket.protocols=TLSv1 TLSv1.2`  -> works only for main site which support TLSv1.2 but fails for SSO which supports TLSv1

Then I tried

https.socket.protocols=TLSv1` -> works for SSO site but once redirected to main site SSL handshake fails

Is there any way at UI level to specify SSL protocol at per request level ?